# Ruby - Connecting to a database on a different thread

Tags: sql, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

When we create thread like this:

```
if Thread_1.alive?
  Thread_1.kill
end
Thread_1 = thread.new do
  sql = String.new
  sql = 'select * from users'
  @dbResult = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
end
```

Suppose sql query executed in 5-30 minute.

If in other method we kill that thread, do sql query still alive?

Do we need wait until database free to access?

Or we can create other sql query like this, and all be work good?

```
if Thread_1.alive?
  Thread_1.kill
end
Thread_2 = thread.new do
  sql = String.new
  sql = "select * from users where id like '105%'"
  @dbResult = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
end
```

Comment: why do you want to kill that thread? yes you can read from the same table from different threads.

Comment: If I kill thread like I describe in second code snippet, should I close connection may be like this: "ActiveRecord::Base.connection. close". Or connection will be closed after I killed thread?

Comment: I think killing a thread causes the connection to close